# Lock Guard Atomic alternative

Tags: c++, c++20, locking, atomic

I've recently written a Vulkan library for creating 2D applications with ease. The catch was I need `std::lock_guard` for my window resize event to resize resources related to the window on a secondary render thread (separate from the main GLFW window thread).

While testing on an AMD machine (running on an AMD APU 5600G) `std::lock_guard` would crash my program. I thought it was strange and tried it again using a blank console program and the same issue happened. Presumably due to issues with memory ordering with caching hits when attempting to lock mutexes on (some?) AMD platforms. The solution was to use `std::atomic` to force standardized memory ordering.

The end result was my own custom `atomic_lock` and `atomic_mutex`. This **should** work similarly to `std::lock_guard` except with an escape timeout (in milliseconds):

```
#pragma once
#ifndef ATOMIC_LOCK
#define ATOMIC_LOCK
    #include <mutex>

    struct atomic_mutex {
    public:
        std::atomic_bool signal;
        std::mutex lock;
    };

    template<bool wait = false, size_t timeout = 100>
    class _NODISCARD_LOCK atomic_lock {
    private:
        std::atomic_bool signal;

    public:
        atomic_mutex& lock;
        
        ~atomic_lock() noexcept { ForceUnlock(); }

        atomic_lock(const atomic_lock&) = delete;

        atomic_lock& operator=(const atomic_lock&) = delete;

        explicit atomic_lock(atomic_mutex& lock) : lock(lock) {
            signal = static_cast<bool>(lock.signal);

            if constexpr(wait) {
                std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
                std::chrono::milliseconds startTime = duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch());
                std::chrono::milliseconds endTime = duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch());
                
                while (signal) {
                    endTime = duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch());
                    
                    if (endTime.count() - startTime.count() >= static_cast<long long>(timeout))
                        break;
                    
                    signal = static_cast<bool>(lock.signal);
                }
            }

            lock.signal = !signal;
            if (signal == false)
                lock.lock.lock();
        }

        bool AcquiredLock() { return !signal; }

        void ForceUnlock() {
            if (!signal) {
                signal = true;
                lock.signal = false;
                lock.lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    };

#endif
```

`atomic_lock` takes in an `atomic_mutex` (struct with atomic_bool & mutex, see above) and attempts to acquire the mutex before the timeout. Then provides a function with the acquired lock state and another to unlock if needed. Then will unlock itself on destruct (out-of-scope).

Usage Pattern:

```
atomic_mutex mylock; // default constructors for std::atomic_bool and std::mutex.

void function(atomic_mutex& mutex) {
    atomic_lock alock(mutex);
    // atomic_lock<true, 500> alock(mutex) // template params optional.
    // Do some multi-threaded work...
}
```

Comment: Did you ask about your problem with `std::lock_guard` on [so]?  Perhaps you made a mistake, or perhaps there's a serious problem with this particular implementation of the standard library.

Comment: If there is such a dire problem with the implementation, it might be worth creating an issue and upstreaming the fix as soon as possible.

Comment: @TobySpeight hard to make a mistake with what was essentially spawn thread -> empty function -> `std::lock_guard`.

Comment: @Incomputable not sure how to do that on the standard library. Also I'm not sure if the problem is the standard library or the system I tested on--which IMO is more likely the case.

Comment: @FatalSleep it might still be good to include the crashing code just as a test code so it could be verified that the code solves the problem.

Comment: @Incomputable will do, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Your standard library is probably fine

> `std::lock_guard` would crash my program.

[`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) is a rather simple class that just calls `lock()` on the `std::mutex` you pass it in its constructor, and calls `unlock()` on it in its destructor. It is almost certainly a programming error if your use of it causes a crash. Possible errors could be that you didn't pass it a valid mutex object, or perhaps it was already locked in the same thread and you try to lock it again.

If calling `lock()`/`unlock()` on a mutex would cause a problem, then I would also expect your class to have a problem since you just call those manually.

> Presumably due to issues with memory ordering with caching hits when attempting to lock mutexes on (some?) AMD platforms.

This is very unlikely. Even if there is a mistake I would not expect this to cause a crash on lock/unlock, but rather cause a race condition that will rarely trigger.

## The interface is not very safe

Constructing an `atomic_lock` may or may not actually lock the `atomic_mutex` object. The caller should immediately call `AquiredLock()` to check whether it was actually locked. Your example usage pattern doesn't even show that. This is in contrast with the default behavior of `std::lock_guard`, which ensures the mutex is locked.

## `signal` is not updated atomically

Another issue is that while `signal` is a `std::atomic_bool`, your class does not read and write `lock.signal` and call `lock.lock()` in an atomic way. Consider two threads constructing an `atomic_lock` object for the same `atomic_mutex` object at the same time:

```
Thread 1                        Thread 2
signal = lock.signal; // false
                                signal = lock.signal; // false
lock.signal = !signal; // true
                                lock.signal = !signal; // true
lock.lock.lock();
                                lock.lock.lock();
```

This causes both threads to immediately lock the mutex, even though it was supposed to be such that one thread would wait for the other to unlock.

## `atomic_lock::signal` should just be a regular `bool`

I don't think you are supposed to access the same `atomic_lock` object from multiple threads. Certainly, `ForceUnlock()` is not thread-safe. That means there is no reason for `atomic_lock::signal` to be a `std::atomic_bool`, it could just be a regular `bool`.

## Consider sleeping instead of spinning

The `while`-loop spins until the mutex is unlocked or some time has elapsed. However, until that happens it uses 100% CPU. This wastes energy for no good reason, and even worse, if you would run this on a computer with only one core, and another thread has locked the mutex, but now your thread has a timeslice, then you can check `lock.signal` all you want but it will never change until your timeslice ends.

I could tell you to use [`std::this_thread::yield()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/yield) or [`std::this_thread::sleep_for()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) in your `while`-loop, but you shouldn't have to do this at all; you should be using `std::lock_guard` and make sure it doesn't crash.

Also note that `std::chrono::system_clock` is not the right clock to use; it can suffer from jumps forwards and backwards, for example due to NTP updates, or to daylight savings time kicking in. You should have used [`std::chrono::steady_clock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) instead.

## Consider using `std::timed_mutex`

Basically, your class implements a mutex with a timeout. There is already a type for that in the standard library: [`std::timed_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/timed_mutex).

Comment: This is great, I did not know about `timed_mutex` or the jump issues with `system_clock`. I figured that the STD was fine, good clarification. I definitely have an issue on my AMD system that's causing this problem as it turns out it has other issues too.